# Activating email system using laravel

Tags: laravel, sendmail, send, mailtrap

I want to activate my project email system. I did the following steps:

1. make notifcation ([part one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2os.jpg) , [part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seu86.jpg))
2. create controller ([make controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk0nG.jpg))
3. create controller ([route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f81PO.jpg))
4. .env for mail with mailtrap ([env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jePpS.jpg))

Everything should work fine but it goes wrong.

**error:**

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1
> Authentication required

I did the following commands but it still didn't work:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

please help me -[F1] - SOS

Comment: welcome to SO. It is better you put codes here instead of code pictures. Because it is easier for those who see your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try `php artisan config:cache` assuming you have setup everything correctly.